# Javascript: extract cell data from table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a scenario where there is a table of 4 rows, in the 4th row is a textbox. When an "onchange" event of the textbox is triggered, I want to extract the data in the cells of the same specific row into another table. and ofcourse my table is consisted of more than one row.

```
<div class="ProductsTable">
    <table class="tablestyle">
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Preview</th>
            <th class="auto-style4">Quantity</th>
            <th class="auto-style15">Selected Items</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row1">
            <td class="auto-style1" id="item_name">Sofa</td>
            <td class="auto-style2" id="item_price">$280.00</td>
            <td class="auto-style3">
                <img class="itemimage" src="images\sofa1.jpg" />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <input class="quantitybox" id="item_quantity" type="text" onchange="get_quantity();" />
            </td>
            <td rowspan="10">
                <table class="InvoiceTable" id="invoice">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="auto-style7">Item</th>
                        <th class="auto-style2">Price</th>
                        <th class="auto-style4">Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And my javascript is:

```
function get_quantity() {
    var table = document.getElementById("invoice");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2)
    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("item_name").innerHTML;
    cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("item_price").innerHTML;
    cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("item_quantity").value;
}
```

How can I create a loop to check through all my table when an "onchange" event is triggered. As I actually have 10 rows in my table.
Preferably without using jquery.

Comment: [rows collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) might be what you're looking for?

Comment: ids should be unique and not used on multiple tags (e.g. multiple cells/rows of a table). These should be classes for styling and access the rows of the table (which could have a unique ID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for a function to copy the content of the changed row, that is the data in each column, into the invoice table.

I expect the rows to be created dynamicaly with some sort of iteration. When iterating I expect a unique number is availabe why this can be used as a general selector.

Here is a function to do this:

```
function get_quantity(rowNumber) {
  var table = document.getElementById("invoice" + rowNumber);
  var row = table.insertRow(1);

  var columns = document.getElementById("row" + rowNumber).childNodes;

  var dataColumnIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    if (columns[i].className == "data") {
      var cell = row.insertCell(dataColumnIndex);
      cell.innerHTML = columns[i].innerHTML;

      dataColumnIndex++;
    }
  }

  var inputQuantity = document.getElementById("item_quantity" + rowNumber).value
  row.insertCell(dataColumnIndex).innerHTML = inputQuantity;
}
```

You select what columns to copy by marking the them with class `data`.
I gets the invoice table by expecting it to have the id `invoice + number`. Fx. `invoice1`. Same goes with each row and the input field.

Here is a [plunker with a full example](http://plnkr.co/edit/owwUiGeVKxJT2cDCU4m4?p=preview).

### Edit

There should only be a single invoice table where all products are added to.
By selecting the same table for row insertion in the function this is fixed.

[This updated plunker has the change](http://plnkr.co/edit/owwUiGeVKxJT2cDCU4m4?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I saw the example in the plunker, but in my real table I have 10 rows of products.. So i added a third row to test, row3, and there is a small problem. In the invoice table, new rows will be added in alignement to the corresponding product in the product table. Is there a way to push the row upwards?

Comment: So you don't need an invoice table per product, just a static invoice table for all products?

Comment: exactly! An invoice table for all the chosen products.. In the sense that whenever a quantity box value is changed, it adds the product, price and the quantity value to the invoice table